# Open gnome terminal new tab in current folder with git prompt command

Tags: bash, command-prompt, gnome-terminal, vte, git-completion

In Fedora 29, added nice branch display to my bash prompt and **new tabs** no longer open in **current** folder:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt ]
then
  GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTAT='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM='auto
  PROMPT_COMMAND='__git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "'
fi
```

**Result:**

- Opening new tab no longer opens in current folder

**Notes:**

- Must use `PROMPT_COMMAND` instead of `PS1` because must have colors and nice things....
- Looks like `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` is being cancelled

**Resourses**:

- [[Tilix] VTE Configuration](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/manual/vteconfig/)
- [Generic solution to not overwrite and break the PS1 prompt, when sourcing vte.sh file](https://github.com/gnunn1/tilix/issues/1509)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function set_git_prompt() {
  __git_ps1 "\u@\h:\w" "\\\$ "
  [ $VTE_VERSION ] && __vte_prompt_command
}

if [ -f /etc/bash_completion.d/git-prompt ]
then
  GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTAT='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES='yes'
  GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM='auto

  PROMPT_COMMAND='set_git_prompt'
fi
```